# Mobile backend starter Notification Alert

Tags: android, mobile, cloud, backend

The mobile backend starter sample guestbook does not provide Notification Alerts,
how can that be implemented?
Tried to modify the GcmIntentService() but had no success to date?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in GcmIntentService() that works for me

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /**
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
         * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
         * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            Log.i(Consts.TAG, "onHandleIntent: message error");
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            Log.i(Consts.TAG, "onHandleIntent: message deleted");
        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType))) {
            String subId = intent.getStringExtra(GCM_KEY_SUBID);
            Log.e(Consts.TAG, "onHandleIntent: subId: " + subId);
            String[] tokens = subId.split(":");
            String typeId = tokens[1];

            // dispatch message
            if (GCM_TYPEID_QUERY.equals(typeId)) {
                Intent messageIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ON_MESSAGE);
                messageIntent.putExtras(intent);
                messageIntent.putExtra("token", tokens[2]);
                boolean isReceived = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
                //Check if the broadcast has been handled, if not show the notification.
                if (!isReceived) {
                    Log.e(Consts.TAG, "A message has been recieved but no broadcast was handled.");
                    generateNotification();
                } else {
                    Log.e(Consts.TAG, "A message has been recieved, broadcasted and handled.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

public void generateNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                    .setContentTitle("A new notification")
                    .setContentText("Some text explaining the notification");

    // all the gubbins needed to make the onclick of the notification open the main activity
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.setAction("com.company.projectname.action.LAUNCH_IT");
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    // link the above onclick with the notification
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
};
```

Comment: I have tried that but does not work for me, must be missing something

Comment: Many thanks for your response
I am not getting any error, 
it just does not display any notification alerts, everything else is working fine.
it displays the messages in the list view.
appears that the GCMIntentService-onHandleIntent(...  is never called to trigger the notification

Comment: If onHandleIntent is not getting called then that gives you somewhere to start. You will need to give MUCH more information in your question as there could be hundreds of reasons why this is not working. Do make sure you are using an emulator rather than a physical device and that you are using this in the cloud rather than localhost.

Comment: I am using an emulator and also tested on my mobile devices, they all receive messages from each other. Notification alerts  work on my "GCM backend" test application but not in my "Mobile Backend" application. Any suggestion where to start looking about the HandleIntent problem?